# How to save charts created with Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I would like to know how to save charts generated by the Spreadsheet API to Google Drive. I've read the documentation and it doesn't mention anything specific, and I've confirmed how to do it in GAS.
If anyone can tell me how to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

There's not direct way to do this on the API.

Possible workarounds include exporting the sheet containing the chart as image or PDF via Drive API's [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), or just use Apps Script.

#### Feature request:

There's a related feature request in Issue Tracker:

- [Export Charts as Images](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230039395)

I'd suggest you to [star it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritize it.

#### Related:

- [Grabbing a Chart as image via JS script and Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824358/grabbing-a-chart-as-image-via-js-script-and-google-sheets-api)
- [Google Sheets API v4 - downloading/saving charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250096/google-sheets-api-v4-downloading-saving-charts)
- [Export Google sheet Chart as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387355/export-google-sheet-chart-as-an-image/60266976#60266976)
- [API to export sheet that contains only a chart as a PDF or image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497773/api-to-export-sheet-that-contains-only-a-chart-as-a-pdf-or-image)

Comment: Thank you. So there is no specific workaround...
Thanks also for the URL of the relevant page. I will take a look at it later.